# Registering new users with Devise in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I am new to rails and working on a rails application.
I have installed the Devise gem and find it helpful in many areas, however I cannot create a new user unless I do it on the Rails Console. I find this especially frustrating. Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions?

When I sign up as an employee I get the following error "CanCan::AccessDenied in JobsController#index"

Also please note that when I verified my user model in devise and I have already included "include Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable"

My jobs_controller.rb file

```
def index
@users = User.all
@user = current_user

@jobs = Job.all
@jobs = Job.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end

# GET /jobs/1
# GET /jobs/1.json
def show
end

# GET /jobs/new
def new
@job = Job.new(:date => Time.now, :date_of_loss => Time.now, :sign_date => Time.now,    :time_called_in => Time.now)
end

# GET /jobs/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /jobs
# POST /jobs.json
def create
@job = Job.new(job_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @job.save
    format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @job }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
    end

  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1.json
  def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @job.update(job_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

 # DELETE /jobs/1
 # DELETE /jobs/1.json
 def destroy
 @job.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to jobs_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_job
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:date, :time_called_in, :date_of_loss, :contact, :job_address, :city, :postal_code, :site_phone, :work_phone, :cell_phone, :email, :referred_by, :insurance_company, :policy_number, :claim_number, :broker, :insurance_address, :insurance_city, :insurance_province, :insurance_postal_code, :insurance_phone,  :insurance_contact, :insurance_email, :customer_name, :customer_address, :authorized, :signed_by_name, :sign_date, :signature, :contact_first_name, :contact_last_name)
end
```

end

My ability model looks like this

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability
def initialize(user)
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.role == "admin"
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.role == "manager"
  can [:read, :update, :create], [Job, Equipment]
  #can [:read, :update, :create], [Equipment]
elsif user.role == "employee"
  can [:read, :update, :create], [Equipment, Job]
  cannot [:create], [Job]
  #can [:read, :update], [Equipment]

end
```

end

Comment: What does your jobs controller look like? Have a look at this: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/956

Comment: @ShivamD I will include my jobs controller in the question

Comment: @ShivamD just included my jobs controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error: `CanCan::AccessDenied in JobsController#index` it's because your user is not authorized to access the `JobsController#index` method and has nothing to do with creating users.

Can you explain what you mean when you say you "Sign up as an employee"? Do you have a roles table or a boolean on the users table to indicate that a user is an employee?

Please post your Ability.rb class (possibly in app/models/ability.rb) as that's where the access controls for cancan are defined.

Try changing this:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
```

to this:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
puts "user.role = #{user.role}"
```

and then **check your logs** to see what the value of user.role is. I'm wondering if your user does not have the role that you think it does.

Comment: just posted the ability.rb class

Comment: Updated my question with something to try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I am going to try

Comment: same error if I try to sign up a new user with the role of an "employee"

Comment: Let's focus on 1 thing at a time. First let's fix your inability to access jobscontroller#index. Did you verify that your user is in fact an employee?

Comment: thank you. I have added your suggestion and I still get the error"CanCan::AccessDenied in JobsController#index"

Comment: But did you look in the log to see what the value is? `puts` just prints to the log.

Comment: Or actually try putting that `puts` line right after this line: `user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)`

Comment: I am not exactly sure if i follow you I'm sorry.

Comment: same error, I have added the line and nothing has changed

Comment: Yes of course you're going to get the same error, that line doesn't do anything different except print something out to your log. I just want you to look in the log and find where it prints `user.role = ` and tell me what the value is.

Comment: did you want me to put that into my rails console? I'm a little confused I am sorry.